# Bulk Insert multiple records and get identity for all using ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I want to batch insert multiple records in sql server database using ADO.NET command/sqldataadapter and get identity value generated for all the rows in a single database trip.

What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using either, SQL server 2005 and 2008 add support for the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, which enables you to return a result-set from an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statement.

Comment: Is there a way to include a column in the OUTPUT clause which was not used in the insert, but on the same row as the input source data?

Comment: @Art - not directly; for an `INSERT` statement, `OUTPUT` is built from the inserted data. You'd have to collect the `OUTPUT` data into a temporary table and re-join it to the input source

Comment: @EdHarper If you were to do this, how could you join back to the original table other than ordinal row position? The ID is an identity, and while you can output it, your original source data does not have this value. I looked and it appears SQL Server 2008+ supports MERGE which would allow you to output columns not referenced in the insert -- but what about a SQL 2005 solution?  Just looking for ideas....

Comment: @Art - Your best bet might be to ask a new question with some details of your data and what you're trying to achieve.